# JavaScript: Explain why the the await operator in a function declaration is the same in a function invocation?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Consider the following I have a call to DynamoDB using this function declaration:

```
async putItem(param: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.PutItemInput): Promise<void> {
    await this.dynamoDb.getDynamoDBDocClient().put(param).promise();
}
```

In a service I am using it like this:

```
try {
    await this.dsDynamoDBService.updateItem({
        TableName: this.dsConfig.aws.dynamoDB.table,
        Key: {
            id: docGenReq.id,
            type: EItemType.REQUEST
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set requestStatus = :requestStatus, requestErrored = :requestErrored',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':requestStatus': EDSRequestRequestDetails.COMPLETE,
            ':requestErrored': false
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    this.logService.error(error);
}
```

Is the `await` in the `try catch` even necessary? If so why?

Comment: Without it you would not be handling the fact that the function returns a Promise.

Comment: So it is always needed? Because of the declaration?

Comment: Well it's needed if you want the code to work properly. Alternatively, you could use a `.then()` chain with the return value, but I don't know why anybody would do that as it's much more confusing.

Comment: This awaits the completion of the operation before your code continues to do anything else, and it handles errors, should any arise; though you're only logging them and aren't doing much else. If you don't care about either of these aspects and just want a fire-and-forget document insertion/update which may or may not complete sometime later… then no, you don't need to `await` or `catch` anything.

Comment: The question title has nothing to do with the body.

Comment: I know i'm getting downvoted, but sometimes you need some straight information from others who are more experienced! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the `await` in the `try` `catch` even necessary? If so why?

Yes, if you want that `try`/`catch` to handle rejections. If you didn't have the `await`, your code wouldn't be doing anything with the promise that `this.dsDynamoDBService.updateItem` returns, which means two things:

1. Your code carries on before the promise is settled, and
2. Your `try`/`catch` won't catch it if the promise is rejected

In contrast, **with** the `await`, your code waits for the promise to settle, and if that settlement is a rejection, it passes that rejection to the `catch` block.

Also note that if you didn't have the `await`, based on the code shown, *nothing* would be handling the promise rejection (if one occurred), leading to an unhandled rejection, which is just like an unhandled error. If this code were running in Node.js or Deno, for instance, that might terminate the process.